# How to recognize parent alias in Join (SELECT?

Tags: mysql, sql

I get the error below:

> ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'c.id' in 'where clause':

```
SELECT *
FROM clients c
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(smpp_user), client_id
     FROM client_accounts
     WHERE client_id = c.id) AS l ON 
     l.client_id = c.id
```

I need use WHERE to group `smpp_user` columns for each `c.id` from main SELECT.

Help please? I believe it's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove `WHERE` clause in your sub query and use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT *
FROM clients c
LEFT JOIN  (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(smpp_user), client_id
    FROM client_accounts
    GROUP BY client_id
) AS l ON l.client_id = c.id
```